# How to remove the wrapper spans from next/image in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I'm leaning Next.js and I have found that `next/image` is wrapping the `img` with two spans and adding inline style to the `img` tag which overriding my class style

How can I remove the inline style and the wrapper HTML tags like `spans` and `divs`?

**My code looks like**

```
import Image from 'next/image';
<Image className={'imgBack'} src={myImg} width="160" height="160" alt="" />
```

**Result**

```
<span style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; width: initial; height: initial; background: none; opacity: 1; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; max-width: 100%;">
    <span style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; width: initial; height: initial; background: none; opacity: 1; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; max-width: 100%;">
    <img alt="" src="/_next/image?url=%sq=75" decoding="async" data-nimg="intrinsic" class="imgBack" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; border: none; margin: auto; display: block; width: 0px; height: 0px; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; max-height: 100%;" srcset="/_next/image?url=%2F_next%s;q=75 1x, /_next/image?url=%2F_next%s;q=75 2x">
    </span>
<span>
```

**Expected result**

```
<img src="./myImg" class="imgBack" alt="" width="160" height="160" />
```

I have read the `next/image` document and I couldn't find a way to fix that.

Comment: The `Image` component produces them, you cannot override that unless you fork and rebuild the component for yourself. The best would be to increase specificity of your css style.

Comment: @BadalSaibo Thank you for your reply! Its really bad how Next implemented image component

Comment: use can use `dangerouslysetinnerhtml` attribute to solve this

Answer (score 15):

##### Using `next/future/image`

**Note:** In Next.js 13, `next/future/image` has been converted to `next/image`, the above is no longer an issue.

From Next.js 12.3, you can use the new `next/future/image` component, which renders a single `<img>` element without any additional `<div>` or `<span>` wrappers by default.

Note that in Next.js 12.2.x the `next/future/image` component was still experimental, and required to be enabled in `next.config.js`.

```js
module.exports = {
    experimental: {
        images: {
            allowFutureImage: true
        }
    },
    // Rest of the config
}
```

---

##### Using `next/image` with `layout="raw"`

Before version 12.2.0 and from 12.1.1, it's possible to render the image without wrappers or styling using the experimental [`layout="raw"`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#experimental-raw-layout-mode) mode.

To enable the raw layout mode, add the following to your `next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    experimental: {
        images: {
            layoutRaw: true
        }
    },
    // Rest of the config
};
```

Then use `layout="raw"` in the `Image` component.

```js
<Image 
    className="imgBack" 
    src={myImg} 
    width="160" 
    height="160" 
    alt="" 
    layout="raw" 
/>
```

Comment: Please, note that this will not work in next js versions older than 12.1.1, in order to upgrade, run: `yarn add next@latest`

Comment: @OverclockedSkid Indeed, thanks for pointing it out. I've added that info to my answer.

Comment: `Error: The layout="raw" experiment has been moved to a new module. Please import 'next/future/image' instead.`

Comment: @ATP If you're using Next.js >12.2 see the other part of my answer about `next/future/image`.

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar problem while migrating from nextjs-11 to nextjs-12.
Nextjs 12 uses a **span** instead of a **div** so just update your CSS file

```
.myImg > span {
//Your CSS 
}
```

Comment: Just changing up the CSS is NOT ENOUGH. These spans come with built-in inline style. Selecting by tag name in CSS does not work for this reason. (I tried it before looking for a way to get rid of the spans)

Comment: This *does* work but you need to specify `!important` on any styles that the span already has, so that they cannot be overridden by the built-in inline styles. Hacky but better than enabling experimental features IMO

Answer (score 0):

Here's what to do if you are using newer Next JS

in components:

```
import Image from "next/future/image";
```

in `next.config.js`:

```
const nextConfig = {
  ...
  experimental: {
    images: {
      allowFutureImage: true,
    },
  },
};
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do some custom styling on your `img` tag, use the following CSS trick:

index.jsx:

```
<div className={classes.imageWrapper}>
   <Image
     width={"42"}
     height={"42"}
     src={"/images/profile/mock-face-2.jpg"}
     alt="mock profile picture"
   />
 </div>
```

styles.module.css:

```
.imageWrapper img {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: You do not need to put a wrapper around `Image`, you can simply write styles in a `className` and these styles will be applied in the `img` element.